# Unfamiliar text in powerline prompt after anaconda (python) installation

Tags: command-line, python, bashrc, anaconda, powerline-plugin

I have installed powerline on Ubuntu. I just installed anaconda for python, and I allowed the installer to make changes in my `.bashrc` file. The following lines were added in my `.bashrc`:

```
# added by Anaconda3 5.3.0 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/home/chinmay/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/chinmay/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/chinmay/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/home/chinmay/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Since the installation, when I start a new terminal session, some text shows up in the prompt:

Before installation

[image: chinmay ~]

After installation

[image: chinmay (e) base ~]

Also, the time it takes to start a new session after I open a new terminal window has increased considerably.

Why has this text appeared and how can I get rid of it?