# Getting rid of conda environment's name when using powerline?

Tags: gnome-terminal, anaconda, conda, powerline-plugin

I have been using `powerline` in Vim for a while. Today I tried it also in my Ubuntu shell (Gnome terminal) and it mostly works well, with one caveat: it annoyingly displays the name of the currently active conda environment like in this question: [Unfamiliar text in powerline prompt after anaconda (python) installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089013/unfamiliar-text-in-powerline-prompt-after-anaconda-python-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I did try doing what was ultimately suggested to that question's author; that is, I did set `changeps1: false` in the .condarc file. This did guarantee that the conda environment name does not show up anymore in the shell prompt if powerline is disabled. However, nothing changes with powerline enabled: conda's environment's name still shows in powerline.

How could I make it sure that the powerline does not display conda's environment's name? Obviously, disabling the environment like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862063/powerline-how-to-remove-e-base-from-terminal-prompt is not an option.